# CS50 Week 1, Credit - If comparison issue? Int size limit?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to CS50 and C and I'm currently working on the Week 1 assignment 'Credit'. I've got most of it working, but I'm running into an issue where no matter how true I feel a statement should be, my if comparison is flagging it false. Is my logic off, or am I missing something? Is there a limit on the size of a number I can use in If comparisons?

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char cardArray[20];
unsigned long creditCard;
string cardType; //String used for checking what type of credit card     has been submitted.
//int remainder;
int n = 0;//Increment array position
int x = 0;

int main(void)
{

creditCard = get_long("Input: "); //Prompt user for CC
printf("%lu", creditCard);

while(creditCard > 0 && creditCard != 0) //Take CC Int and convert to Char Array for math functions
{
    cardArray[n] = (creditCard % 10); //Modulus creditCard remainder
    //printf("%i\n", n); //Array indices check
    creditCard = (creditCard / 10); //Reduce creditCard by factor of 10
    printf("%d\n", cardArray[n]);
    n += 1; //increment Array indices
}

printf("Pos 15: %d\n", cardArray[15]);

//Use if >= to check size of creditCard
if(creditCard > 1000000000000 && creditCard <= 9999999999999){printf("X3: %s\n", cardType); //Check for creditCard length of 13 
    if(cardArray[12] == 4){
        cardType = "VISA\n";
    }
}else     printf("X: %s\n", cardType); 

if(creditCard >= 100000000000000 && creditCard <= 999999999999999){ printf("X1: %s\n", cardType);//Check for creditCard length of 15
    if(cardArray[14] == 3 && (cardArray[13] == 4 || cardArray[13] == 7)){//If 15 AND starts with 34 OR 37 then set card value to American Express
        cardType = "AMEX\n"; 
    }    
}else     printf("X: %s\n", cardType);

if(creditCard >= 1000000000000000 && creditCard <= 9999999999999999){printf("X2: %s\n", cardType); //Check for creditCard length of 16
    if(cardArray[15] == cardArray[15]){//Does it start with 4? set card value to Visa
        cardType = "VISA\n";
            printf("%s", cardType); 
    }
else     printf("X: %s\n", cardType);
    if(cardArray[15] == 5 && (cardArray[14] == 1 || cardArray[14] == 2 || cardArray[14] == 3 || cardArray[14] == 4 || cardArray[14] == 5)){//Does it begin with 51, 52, 53, 54, or 55? set card value to Master Card     
        cardType = "MASTERCARD\n";
    }    
}    
else cardType = "INVALID\n";

printf("%s", cardType); 

}
```

I've tested with several printf lines to see where my code is going. If I change comparisons to something like 1 == 1 I can flag the comparison as true, but using comparisons like creditCard >= 1000000000000 will always fail, even if I'm passing along 10000000000000.

Comment: I suggest you try to do a little {rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. Especially the first loop. What will the value of `creditCard` be after that first loop? Then think about how the condition `creditCard > 1000000000000 && creditCard <= 9999999999999` could ever be true.

Comment: Try printing some of your numerical literals.

Comment: You are asking for trouble by using literal constants in your code, and it is bad practice.  Define symbolic constants to make your code maintainable, readable and less error prone.

Comment: `creditCard > 0 && creditCard != 0` -- is the second condition `creditCard != 0` ever reachable for an `unsigned` type? What does `creditCard > 0` evaluate to if `creditCard == 0`? Doesn't evaluation of the conditional stop when `creditCard > 0` fails? (hints: `No, 0, Yes`)

Comment: Yes, the second condition is reachable. `creditCard != 0` is evaluated whenever `creditCard > 0` is true. It is just redundant.

Comment: @Clifford : Thanks for the input! Would you mind giving me an example of literal vs symbolic constants? I can picture that "literal" must mean something like the "1000000000000", but what would a symbolic equivalent be?

Comment: @MatthewDF A meaningful name defined in one place with the numeric value, and thereafter used by name, rather than "magic numbers" - but really, you could have Googled that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `unsigned long` on your target is likely a 32 bit value. 2<sup>32</sup> = 4294967296, so clearly the comparison with 10000000000000 for example will always evaluate to false.

If your compiler did not issue any warnings, you should look at your compiler settings.

Change the type of `creditCard` to `unsigned long long` or better `uint64_t` (declared in `<stdint.h>`).  Then you should also specify the the literal integer with the `ULL` suffix, eg:

```
creditCard >= 100000000000000ULL
```

However, the implementation is seriously flawed.  You get the card number as an integer then convert it to a string.  Since your data type will not hold a credit card number, both the string and the integer will be incorrect.  Credit card numbers are not arithmetic objects, and storing as an integer is a bad idea for more reasons that just range - even a `uint64_t` is only good for 19 digits - which may be enough for now, but possibly not in future.  The number should be received and processed as a string.  The advantages are that you can perform more sophisticated validation, allow digit grouping spaces, and will not loose leading zero digits.

String comparisons on normalised digit strings (i.e. with spaces removed) will work as well as an arithmetic comparison.  For example:

```
if( strcmp( cardNumberString, "10000000000" ) >= 0 )
```

achieves the same result as:

```
if( cardNumberUnsLongLong >= 10000000000ULL )
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil : I take your point regarding "will not work", though I meant in the sense that the code is _semantically incorrect_ rather than that the expression being syntactically invalid.  Changed it for clarity as suggested.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : I have used older compilers that will not accept literal constants out of range of plain `int`, so it is a habit and a preference rather then a requirement.  The avoidance of implicit conversions is not a bad idea in any event.

Comment: On most modern 64-bit systems, `unsigned long` is 64 bits -- but I think it's still 32 bits on Windows. The standard guarantees at least 32 bits. In general, don't assume  either that it's wider than 32 bits, or that it isn't.

Comment: @KeithThompson : Arguably _all_ Windows plus _all_ 32 bit platforms (desktop, embedded, with or without an OS) _is_ most systems! ;-). However your point is well made, modified text. It seems if this code fails in the way described, in this case it is 32 bit. For information: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models